# Building Laravel query adding where statement by relationship's field

Tags: php, laravel

I am not able to construct simple Laravel query.
I have `translation` with categories (`translation.category_id` is foreign key to `category.id`). Moroever category also has property `is_technical`.

What I need is:
- get all translations where translation's category.is_technical = 1.

Currently I am haveing this query:

```
 $match = ['lang1_code' => $langfrom, 'lang2_code' => $langto];
 $translation = Translation::where($match)->orderByRaw("RAND()")->take(4)->get();
```

But this query doesn't join category (I have relationship in my db and also in my models). Thus how to join category and set where is_Technical = 1?

I believe this is basic question, but I am new to Laravel and I cannot find answer in documentation.

Comment: Have you defined the relationship between the models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need whereHas. See Laravel Document for more info
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Here is an example, correct your model name.

```
//Translation.php
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');
}

// query
$translation = Translation::whereHas('category', function($q) {
    $q->where('is_technical', '=', 1);
})->where($match)->orderByRaw("RAND()")->take(4)->get();
```